# post form values to html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I want to POST form values and display them on another html page using Javascript. No server-side technology should be used. I have a function that posts the values but to read the values to another html page, I think I am missing something. Below is the code.
Any help? Thanks in advance.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function post_to_page(path, params, method) {
  method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default, if not specified.
  var form = document.createElement("form");
   form.setAttribute("method", method);
   form.setAttribute("action", path);
   form.setAttribute("target", "formresult");

    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    // creating the 'formresult' window with custom features prior to submitting the form
    window.open('target.htm', 'formresult', 'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');

    form.submit();

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="target.htm" method="post">
<div>
USB No: <input name="usbnum" id="usbnum" type="text"/><br />
USB Code: <input name="usbcode" id="usbcode" type="text"/>
</div>
<button onclick="post_to_page()">Try it</button>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe helpful: [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage). Since you're not submitting any data to the server you don't actually want to _POST_ but rather pass infromation from one window to another. As you're probably passing the same origin policy, you have access to the other window's _Window_ (returned from the `window.open` call) so there are many ways to pass the information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TGd7V/) of moving data from one *Window* to another

```
<!-- HTML -->
<textarea id="foo"></textarea><br/>
<input id="bar" value="click" type="button"/>
```

and the real code to make it work, which assumes you pass the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

```
// JavaScript
var whatever = 'yay I can share information';

// in following functions `wnd` is the reference to target window
function generateWhatever(wnd, whatever) { // create the function actually doing the work
    return function () {wnd.document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = whatever};
} // why am I using a generator? You don't have to, it's a choice

function callWhenReady(wnd, fn) { // make sure you only invoke when things exist
    if (wnd.loaded) fn(); // already loaded flag (see penultimate line)
    else wnd.addEventListener('load', fn); // else wait for load
}

function makeButtonDoStuff() { // seperated button JS from HTML
    document
    .getElementById('bar')
    .addEventListener('click', function () {
        var wnd = window.open(window.location); // open new window, keep reference
        callWhenReady(wnd, generateWhatever(wnd, whatever)); // set up function to be called
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', function () {window.loaded = true;}); // set loaded flag (do this on your target, this example uses same page)
window.addEventListener('load', makeButtonDoStuff); // link button's JavaScript to HTML when button exists
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html5 you can use localStorage.  Otherwise a query string or cookies are your other options.

You said you didn't want the server involved...why are you calling submit?

[Edit]
@Paul S's comment/answer looks very helpful.  But you might look at something like the jQuery PostMessage plugin if you need it to be cross browser compatible.

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You can't get POST values using JavaScript. You can use GET method to pass values.

Answer (score 0):

You don't require a POST request to send data from one page to another. Simply use LocalStorage to do the trick. Just call a Javascript function on form submission. This may help:

HTML:

```
<form id="form1" action="target.htm" method="post">
    <div>
        USB No: <input name="usbnum" id="usbnum" type="text"/><br />
        USB Code: <input name="usbcode" id="usbcode" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <button onclick="post_to_page()">Try it</button>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function post_to_page() {
    localStorage.value = "Your content here";
    window.location = "nextpage.html";
}
```

This will save the data locally and go to the next page. In the next page, simply call this function to retrieve the stored data:

```
function get_stored_data() {
    alert(localStorage.value);
}
```

You can simply assign it to a div, textbox other Javascript variable.